# Why are upper bounds only defined on subsets of preordered sets?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

So I recently was reading through spivaks calculus and just learned the least upper bound property.
I noticed that in the definition the sets in consideration are always subsets of $\mathbb{R}$
This made me curious as to why only subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ were considered and why they have a notion of upper bounds.

Having looked up the definition of what an upper bound of a set is on Wikipedia I came across this rather confusing definition.

an upper bound or majorant
of a subset S of some preordered set (K, ≤) is an element of K which is
greater than or equal to every element of S.

I do not know what a preordered set is but im willing to guess that $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of one .

So basically my question is what is a preordered set and what about them makes them able to have upper and lower bounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you not try clicking the relevant link in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: There is not an upper bound for $\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid x^2<2\}$ in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes there is. There is no **least** upper bound.

Comment: @bof:  you're right.  That's what I meant

Comment: @rob arthan I did and I understood that a preordered set is a generalisation of an equivalence relation and a partially ordered set which I assume imply all partially ordered sets are preordered sets so does that mean $\mathbb{R}$ is a partially ordered set?

Comment: A preordered set is a set equipped with a relation that is reflexive and transitive (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder). The usual ordering relation on $\Bbb{R}$ is a preorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pre-ordered set is a set $X$ with a relation, often denoted by $\le$, that obeys two simple axioms: $x \le x$ for all $x \in X$ and transitivity: If $x \le y$ and $y \le z$ both hold, then so does $x \le z$. If you think of $x \le y$ as "$y$ is at least as big as $x$", these properties make intuitive sense. A common example is set inclusion, so $X$ is all subsets of $\Bbb N$ say and $x \le y$ is defined to mean $x$ is a subset of $y$. Then $x=\{0,1\}$ and $y=\{2,3\}$ are not "comparable", neither $x \le y$ nor $y \le x$ holds, but the set $\{x,y\}$ has a least upper bound, namely $z=\{0,1,2,3\}$: both sets are smaller: $x \le z$ and $y \le z$ and there can be no smaller common upper bound. One can easily show that this $X$ with this (non-linear, unlike $\Bbb R$) pre-order also has the least upper bound property.

It's an important defining feature of $\Bbb R$ that it has this lub property, it's what distinguishes it from $\Bbb Q$; it "fills up" the rational number line with relevant real numbers like $\sqrt{2}, \pi$ and $e$.. That's why it's used a lot in analysis. But the phenomenon of preordered sets is everywhere in maths and having the lub property can be very relevant there as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb R$ is a well-ordered set.  For every $x,y \in \mathbb R$ either $x > y$ or $y<x$ or $x=y$  And, for every non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ that subset inherits the ordering.  So, those sub-sets are well-orderd.

However, just because the subset is well-ordered, doesn't mean it has the least upper bound property.  The set of rational numbers such that $x\in\{\mathbb Q|x<\sqrt 2\}$ does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb Q.$  i.e. $\sqrt 2$ is the least upper bound, but $\sqrt 2$ is not in $\mathbb Q$ yet there are infinitely many elements in $\mathbb Q$ that are arbitrarily close to $\sqrt 2$

Partially ordered sets and pre-ordered sets are not as restricted as well ordered and totally ordered sets.

There will be $x,y \in S$ such that $x>y$ however it may not be true for every $x,y$

For example, consider a tree.  We might say $x>y$ if $y$ if there is a path down the branch from $x$ to $y.$  But, if $x,y$ lie on different branches we cannot say anything about how $x$ relates to $y.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: so are totally ordered sets basically preordered sets?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is not *well-ordered* the property in the first paragraph is called *linearly ordered* (or totally ordered).